# Replace a string before a certain line

Tags: text-processing, sed, perl

I have one file like:

```
ID_SOUR_CALENDAR BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMPRESS 0 ,
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
ID ,
ID_SOUR ,
PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
```

I want to replace the ',' by ')' in the line just before the line containing PRIMARY.

The result should be:

```
ID_SOUR_CALENDAR BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMPRESS 0 )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
ID ,
ID_SOUR )
PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `GNU sed`:

```
sed  'N;s/,\(\s*\n.*PRIMARY\)/)\1/;P;D' file

ID_SOUR_CALENDAR BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMPRESS 0 )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
ID ,
ID_SOUR )
PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
```

- `N`  Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.
- `P`  Print up to the first embedded newline of the current pattern space.
- `D`  Delete up to the first embedded newline in the pattern space.  Start next cycle, but skip reading from the input if there is still data in the pattern space.

Answer (score 9):

Try reversing the file, doing the string replacement on the line **after** PRIMARY, then re-reversing the file:

```
tac file | sed '/PRIMARY/ {n; s/,$/)/}' | tac
```

Comment: @SivaPrasath - not really, this will fail if the input contains consecutive lines matching `PRIMARY`

Comment: @don_crissti ur right!!! at least it works for the OP's input.

Comment: @don_crissti *"not really"* what? This is a solution for "Replace a string before a certain line" exactly as `sed` would do this on its own for the positive offset (**AFTER** a certain line/regex). You tried to judge the solution as for some other use case, not the one at hand.

Answer (score 7):

try this,

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/,([^\n,]*\n[^\n]*PRIMARY)/)$1/g'
```

This will replace the last `,` with `)` in lines before any line including `PRIMARY`.

Explanation

- `perl -0777` slurp whole file (read as one line)
- `s/search_pattern/replacement/g` Substitute search pattern with replacement globally

Comment: Note that `. ` meta char won't cross line boundaries, unless the `/s` modifier is in effect. Hence, you can change the regex to `s/,(?=[^,]*\n.*PRIMARY)/)/g`

Comment: ? I don't use `.` in my regex.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `ed` rather than `sed` you can use a regex address with negative offset:

```
g/PRIMARY/-1 s/,$/)/
```

Ex.

```
$ printf 'g/PRIMARY/-1 s/,$/)/\n,p\nq\n' | ed -s file
ID_SOUR_CALENDAR BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMPRESS 0 )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
ID ,
ID_SOUR )
PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
```

or (for in-place editing)

```
printf 'g/PRIMARY/-1 s/,$/)/\nwq\n' | ed -s file
```

The replacement will match ALL instances of `/PRIMARY/` - if you only want to replace the first, remove the `g` modifier.

Comment: +1 for use of The Standard Text **Ed**itor

Answer (score 2):

With **POSIX**-*ly* `sed` you can do the following:

```
sed -e '
    /PRIMARY/!{x;1!p;d;}
    x;s/,/)/;$G
' input-file.txt
```

**Output:**

```
ID_SOUR_CALENDAR BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0  COMPRESS 0 )
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
ID ,
ID_SOUR )
PRIMARY INDEX ( CALENDAR_DATE );
```

**Working:**

- For non-PRIMARY lines, we save the line and print the one we saved in the hold.
- And for the PRIMARY, we retrieve the previous and effect the transformation.