# sed: replace part of text in previous line if match is found

Tags: sed

I want to replace `create_test` in the file with `#create_test` if the next line contains `psfxxx_16_pi`. How can I do it with sed for the whole file containing this?

Input file content:

```
create_test -type hard -outer { 1.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_north_re_0 }

create_test -type hard -outer { 0.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_south_re_1 }
```

Output file:

```
#create_test -type hard -outer { 1.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_north_re_0 }

#create_test -type hard -outer { 0.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_south_re_1 }
```

Comment: I can do it with perl, but I am looking for a compact one liner command using sed or awk. Thank you Mr. Shunz for the format.

Comment: May be helpful? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/466798/replace-a-string-before-a-certain-line

Comment: I'm always curious when I see requests for one-liners; what's wrong with a perl solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sed '/^create_test/ {N; /psfxxx/ s/^/#/}' file
#create_test -type hard -outer { 1.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_north_re_0 }

#create_test -type hard -outer { 0.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_south_re_1 }

create_test -type hard -outer { 1.0000 } { \
    vsfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_north_re_0 }

create_test -type hard -outer { 0.0000 } { \
    vsfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_south_re_1 }
```

When encountering "create_test" it appends the next line, and if that contains "psfxxx", it prefixes the "#".

Comment: Thank you RudiC. I tried. It replaces only the first occurance in the input text file.
output:
#create_test -type hard -outer { 1.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_north_re_0 }

create_
test -type hard -outer { 0.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_south_re_1 }

Comment: Hi! RudiC. Your fix works. Great! my input file had an issue. It had create_ in one line and test... in the next. Fixed it and it's working fine now. You are a genius.

Comment: You can see in my sample output that it replaces on matching records, and doesn't if no match. What's different in your input file?  Hoppla - cross post.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed` method:

```
$ sed -zE 's/create_test([^\n]*\n[^\n]*psfxxx_16_pi)/#create_test\1/g' file
#create_test -type hard -outer { 1.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_north_re_0 }

#create_test -type hard -outer { 0.0000 } { \
    psfxxx_16_pi/psfop/deadline_south_re_1
```

Answer (score 0):

If awk will do:

```
awk '/psfxxx_16_pi/{prev = "#" prev} {print prev} {prev = $0} END {print}'
```

Here, I print the previous line (saved in `prev`) for each line, and save `$0` for the next iteration in `prev`. If the line matches, I add `#` to `prev`. At the end, print the last line.